# Override only one method in an overloaded method of Java interface

Tags: java, android, interface, overriding, overloading

I have this code:

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
    abstract void processFinish(JSONObject output);
    abstract void processFinish(String output);
}
```

I use it like this:

```
new AsyncResponse(){
    @Override
    public void processFinish(JSONObject output) {
        //code
    }

    @Override
    public void processFinish(String output) {
        //code
    }
}
```

When I overload only one method(for example only the JSONObject) it gives the error:
 "*Class 'Anonymous class derived from AsyncResponse' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'processFinish(String)' in 'AsyncResponse'*"

**If it is possible, I need to overload only one method, not both.**
I don't know if it's something similiar in AsyncTask where only the `doInBackground` is required to be `Override`-ed and the onther methods are optional.

*Not sure if I have used the right programming terms for my question, but I hope that, what I need to do is clear.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible unless you split the interface into two:

```
public interface AsyncResponseWithJSONObject {
    void processFinish(JSONObject output);
}
public interface AsyncResponseWithString {
     void processFinish(String output);
}
```

The classes that can handle strings implement the latter and classes that can handle JSON implement the former.

> Then why can `AsyncTask` do it?

`AsyncTask` is an *abstract class*, not an interface. When extending an abstract class, you only need to implement `abstract` methods. Interfaces on the other hand requires all methods to be implemented. (because all methods in an interface are implicitly abstract)

So you can try using an abstract class as well:

```
public abstract class AsyncResponse {
    public void processFinish(JSONObject output) {

    }

    public void processFinish(String output) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are implementing an interface, you have to override all the methods present in it. There is no way around it.

If you want to partially override it, make AsyncResponse a class, like this :

```
public class AsyncResponse {
    public void processFinish(JSONObject output) {
    }
    public void processFinish(String output) {
    }
}
```

Now when you extends this class, there is no requirement that you have to override all the methods.

Answer (score 2):

you could add default to your interface (Java8 onwards)

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
    abstract void processFinish(JSONObject output);
    default void processFinish(String output) {
        // some code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What happened to?:

```
public interface AsyncResponse<T> {
    void processFinish(T output);
}
```

Even if it's not overloading, it seems simple In my eyes.